# How can I get the text out of an slider in elementor?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to drag the text out of an elementor slideshow. So that the slide image is on the right side and the text is on the left. And the text changes according to the slide. Is there a way to do that?
I'm doing the entire project on WP and elementor so I have to use those but I also know a bit of CSS so if there's a certain CSS code that helps me with doing this I'd be happy to try it.

there's actually no options in the elementor editor itself. and I've tried giving it right and left properties, changing the position attribute and some other tweaks but nothing seems to be able to drag the text out of the div which contains it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just watch this small video. And then you're able to convert anything into slider with the help of elementor in WordPress.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DP3Y0pUy4xg&pp=ygUlY29udmVydCBhbnl0aGlnIGludG8gc2xpZGVyIGVsZW1lbnRvcg%3D%3D

Thank you!!!